# Importing CSV file as polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv, import

I downloaded a CSV file for a city nearby. The file has columns `"SHAPE_Leng"`, `"SHAPE_Area"`, `"lat"`, and `"lon"`. I assume with represents a polygon. What are the steps to import that data and create a polygon?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, your assumption may not be correct. It is not possible to reconstitute a polygon from a single vertex without additional information. (e.g., a circle's radius, or an ellipse's semimajor/semiminor/orientation,...). Even generating  a set of Voronoi polygons assumes that the point was selected to be the location from which such regions are generated. If you want polygons, you should look to the original provider for polygon data.

Comment: You should share the whole file to get help.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have the data to recreate the polygons. The shape area and leng are just measurements of actual polygon (area and perimeter length of the polygon) and lat lon will only give you a point (probably centroid or some point inside the polygon).

To recreate the polygon you need the coordinate of all vertex, in csv file these are often found in a field filled with wkt string.

As the shape len and area field hint that the data was exported from gis data you may look if they offer other export format that include actual geometry.